# Apostrophe breaks syntax highlight in .ini file

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual studio Pro 2015, and when I'm working whit an .ini file with apostrophes, the syntax highlight think that's a string :

[syntax exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6TI9.png)

Is there a way to stop apostrophes recognition when working on .ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this is as workaround

```
&apos;
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work, this is read as &apos; not as '